# Bayesian Time Series model in R

Tags: r, bayesian, forecasting

Similar to the scenario described in [this paper](http://allman.rhon.itam.mx/~mendoza/Foresight.pdf), I need to forecast a seasonal time series with only a few periods. I am working with about 2 years of daily revenue data, and I want to forecast the rest of the year. I need to be accurate on the monthly level. I have tried methods like fitting ARIMA models and TBATS models recommended by Hyndman, but I have not been impressed by their accuracy so far.

Has anyone tackled a problem like this before? I would like to try a Bayesian model, but I don't have a lot of experience fitting non-frequentist models, and would need an explanation of how to do so for a time series.

Comment: If you want to go Bayesian, I would recommend familiarizing yourself with https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstan/index.html. However, I'm not sure that taking a Bayesian approach will improve your accuracy. Maybe you could considering changing the frequency of your data? Aggregate to weekly?

Comment: Aggregating to weekly does show some promise, but then I'm not sure how to handle weeks that overlap into multiple months. I could just divide the week by 7 and allocate by number of days that fall into each month, but my data exhibits large weekly seasonality, so this sort of allocation is likely to be innacurate.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I would recommend fitting the weekly data with auto.arima in the R forecast package. I would also recommend examining the ACF.

Comment: It is necessary for me to report a monthly forecastin addition to a full year forecast. Thus, for a week like May 29-June 4, the point forecast would need to be allocated partially to May and partially to June.

Comment: You could always do a regression of the true monthly numbers against the monthly numbers using the weekly interpolation technique you describe.